# How do you change the DNS servers for a NIC in a Windows Cluster?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, windows-cluster

I need to change the primary and secondary DNS ips completely. Are there any precautions that need to be taken?

Comment: The new DNS servers are in the same DNS and activity directory domain as the old ones.

Comment: Its quite possible that these links will help: [Modify Network Settings for a Failover Cluster](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725775(v=ws.11).aspx) and [Understanding Requirements for Failover Clusters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771404(v=ws.11).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the DNS servers on the NIC of a cluster member the same way you do for any other Windows computer, in the properties of the NIC. There's nothing special about it.

You do not need to change anything in the cluster settings.

Matthieu's cautionary warning about making sure you configure the hosts to use the correct DNS servers is accurate, but it isn't specific or unique to failover clustering. The same holds true for any AD domain joined machine.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you have to be carefully has a windows cluster is using an Active Directory user account to be able to run.
So if you have to move your cluster to be a dns client of a new dns server you have to make sure it's in exactly the same DNS and Active Directory domain you are currently running in, otherwise your cluster will goes down.

Here the [Microsoft requirement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771404(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_Account_Infrastructure) for Windows server 2008 but they are the same for your version.

To change the network config you have to look at the "Failover Cluster Manager" you'll find the network config available you can change it from here.

Comment: I did look for the network config there but was unable to find it. Could you point me to the specific area in the Failover Cluster Manager?

Comment: You should find the network details on the left side of the Failover Cluster Manager [link](https://goo.gl/VRCbzx) (Step7)
Or you should be able to modify it directly at the windows level from the server manager here is an example [link](https://goo.gl/iMYEGt)  (just before step 5)

Comment: I have looked at all of that documentation before I asked my question here and it is unclear about updating DNS for the cluster.

Comment: You question is to vague here, i have pointed you to the Microsoft requirement regarding a Windows cluster, and where you can do the change. So i don't understand what you are missing, any way at a first stage you need to have a very good understanding on how a cluster working on a window server so from here you can understand your own setup and then only then perform the proper actions.